# Laravel User Policy Is Returning The Authenticated User's Information And Not The External User

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I created a Laravel policy called "UserPolicy" which is supposed to filter out users that do not have the permission to edit, delete, and update other users. The problem is that I am trying to pass an external user's information to the policy. But instead, it just returns the authenticated users information.

My Policy:

```
public function edit(?User $user)
{
    if(auth()->check()) {
        dd($user);
        $userpower = auth()->user()->roles()->min('power');
        if($userpower <= $user->power) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

My Controller:

```
public function edit(User $user)
{
    $this->authorize('edit', $user);

    $roles = Role::all();
    $user = User::where('steamid', $user->steamid)->with('roles')->first();

    return view('manage.includes.users.edit')->with(compact('user', 'roles'));
}
```

For example, I am the user Bob. I am trying to edit the user, John. As a test, I included the dd() function to dump the $user information that is passing into the Policy. After seeing the results, instead of John's information being passed, it is Bob's. How can I make it where it is John's information and not Bob's.

Thank you for your help, if you need more information please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter is the authenticated user. The second parameter is the resource. Try defining your policy as:

```php
/**
 * Can a guest user, or an authenticated user (let's call this first user Bob)
 * edit another user (let's call that second user John) ?
 */
public function edit(?User $bob, User $john)
{
    //
}
```